# Variable from partial to container

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

### The goal

I need to do something like this on my layout `/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<% if free %>
  <!-- do something -->
<% end %>
```

BUT, the `free` variable must be declared on the partials or yielded views, not in controllers or models – this is a visualization rule.

### The problem

Currently, I'm doing the following in my `/controllers/welcome.rb`:

```
def index
  @free = true
end
```

The point is: this isn't reponsibility of the controller and then I don't feel things good this way.

### Environment

CentOS 6.5 with Rails 4.1.

Comment: Interesting. Would you be more comfortable declaring in the view? Or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this isn't reponsibility of the controller and then I don't feel
>   things good this way.

I understand. Although you should not be declaring variables on your view, that could get messy. Imagine if there's a bug with the variable and you would be looking into all your views that set the variable looking for the problem. IMHO it is way better to declare it as a helper in your ApplicationController, that way all the views will have your variable already defined and it will be up to you to use it or not.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :free

  protected
    def free
      true
    end
end
```

This way you would be able to override the 'free' method in other controllers if the value of free should be different.